# How to prevent Flash Builder from running/debugging from the cache?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've been bitten by this a few times, and when it shows up it can make simple problems very difficult to solve. For example:

```
var x:int = y + 1;
if(x < y) {
  trace("Okay, you got me.");
}
```

Under what conditions will that trace show up? Normally it shouldn't, but if the player is using its cache it might. Sometimes I don't realize what's going on until an unreachable breakpoint gets triggered.

Is there a way to prevent Flash Builder/the debug player from playing out-of-date content?

Answer (score 1):

I have never had this problem. But use **Build Automatically** to force Flash Builder to build every time you change a file. Be sure to setup your Actionscript Applications in the Project properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
look for an option "reset fcsh"

in my ant script (fdt) i use.

```
    <target name="resetCompiler">
    <fdt.launch.resetFCSH />
</target>
```